# Solutions to a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

My question is can the pairs $$(1, 2), (4, 8), \text{and } (−1, 5)$$ all be solutions to a linear system with two equations in two variable?

My intuition says no as the pairs $(1, 2), (4, 8)$ are linearly dependent, but I don't know how to make a formal argument as to why they cannot be a solution to a linear system with two equations in two variable.

Comment: Hint. Can you find one linear equation in two variables satisfied by the first two of the vectors?

Comment: Can you think of an equation in two variables that is satisfied by every x and y?

Comment: $2x-y=0$? is that what you are hinting at?

Comment: but then $(-1,5)$ doesn't satisfy this equation

Comment: Try with a general equation in two variable $ax + by = c.$ Can you find  $a, b$ and $c$?

Comment: Obviously the vectors are elements of the kernel of the zero-matrix.  OTOH, the vectors don't lie on a straight line.

Comment: I mean there is the obvious trivial example, $x = x, y = y.$ So what conditions do you require for the system?

Comment: Sorry, Assume both equations have 2 variables.

Comment: So I am gathering that these 3 pairs cannot be solutions to a linear system with two equations in two variable assuming that both equations have 2 variables